# Setting Authorization header in HttpResponse throws "borrowed value does not live long enough"

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am using actix-web to authenticate a user in a REST api. The endpoint for authenticating a user sets the "Authorization" header of the response object to a generated token.

```
async fn signin(request: web::Json<UserAndPw>) -> impl Responder {
  let token = String::from("thisisatest");
  HttpResponse::Ok()
    .header(AUTHORIZATION, HeaderValue::from_static(&token))
    .json(ApiResponse {...})
}
```

This is error occurs when compiled:

```
.header(AUTHORIZATION, HeaderValue::from_static(&test_token))
                       -------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                   |                        |
   |                   |                        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                   argument requires that `test_token` is borrowed for `'static`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `token` is a local variable and a reference to it (`&token`) is definitely not with a static lifetime. The compiler error explains it and shows it to you.

You probably want to create a [`HeaderValue`](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/http/header/struct.HeaderValue.html) instance some other way, not via `from_static`. For example like this: `HeaderValue::from_str(&token)`.

Comment: It works if I convert the token into  bytes and use that to create the HeaderValue. Thanks.